# No puedo actualizar mongodb desde Mongose

Tags: nodejs, express, mongoose

Trato de agregar datos a mi `Array` por `mongose` pero no pasa nada, en la `DB` continua igual, no puedo ni cambiarlo.

**Modelo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Dao**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**DB**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> No importa cuantas veces ejecute, no se cambia, no se agrega y no sale error

Comment: A esta pregunta le falta mucha información. Por ejemplo, saber si el navegador está devolviendo el mensaje "Correcto". También es necesario saber si mongodb está dando algún tipo de error. O si el propio servidor de express está lanzando alguna excepción. Por último estaría bien que proporcionases el código mínimo para poder reproducir tu problema, en vez de sólo capturas del mismo.

Comment: `No importa cuantas veces ejecute, no se cambia, no se agrega y no sale error`, es justamente el problema, no pasa nada y no me devuelve error, pero si el mensage de `Actualizado` al requerir `/update`, aunque use `update(), updateOne(), updateMany()` con indices `$push, $set o sin estos`

Comment: Dejando a un lado lo que nos comenta nuestro compañero @Ale Sanchez, que seria importante para resolver tu problema.
Has probado realizando esto:
`servicios.updateMany({"title": "Marketing Digital"},{$push:{servicio:ser})`